# Self-hosted Bitcoin wallet for Linux with API?

Tags: wallet, api, linux, hosting

I'm looking for some Bitcoin wallet software I can host locally on my Linux server that provides either an API or webhooks for detecting when Bitcoin transactions have completed. I also need a way to initiate transactions (i.e. tell the wallet to send Bitcoins to an address).

Does anyone know of anything? I know there is coinpunk, but I don't see anything about it having such functionality.

Comment: Hi! I have the same issue. I am working on such an open source project, but it is has been coming only few days now and it is not yet in shape for release. However I'll post more information in few days/weeks.

Comment: That would be helpful! If anyone else's knows the answer now, please post!

Comment: What functionality do you need that isn't provided by bitcoin-core with rpc calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you look at bitcoind?
It does everything you are looking for.

-port=           Listen for connections on  (default: 8333 or testnet: 18333)

-walletnotify=    Execute command when a wallet transaction changes (%s in cmd is replaced by TxID)

-alertnotify=     Execute command when a relevant alert is received (%s in cmd is replaced by message)

http://paste.ee/p/IBU79

And all of your transactions you do via rpc  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

enjoy!

Comment: I think bitcoind will quite possibly be a winner! Thank you!